# Angularjs promise?

Tags: angularjs

The problem is that when i get responses, they are not in the right order, for example, I get 1.name, 3.name, 4.name, 2.name, 5.name. How can I get responses in right order, like in devIds array?

```
var devIds = ['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']


devIds.map(function(id){                   
    DeviceService.getDevInfo(id).then(function(response){
         console.log(response.name)
       })
  })
```

I had pretty much the same problem in React but I fixed it like this

```
axios.all(array.map(el => axios.get(`/item/${el}`)))
     .then(data => console.log(data));
```

Here I am trying something like this and it doesnt work

```
Promise.all(devIds.map(function(el){DeviceService.getDevInfo(el)}))
     .then(function(res){console.log(res)});
```

Comment: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$q#all

Comment: Note: saying "it doesn't work" is not helping us to help you. Say precisely what you expect to happen, and what happens instead.

Comment: Sorry, in developer tools in network I see that all http requests are done, but somehow I do not get that responses in console log that is in than(). As i wrote above, i expect to get responses in order like in the array. But I dont.

Comment: Use the $q.all service, as I linked to in my first comment.

Comment: You forgot to `return` when you went from arrow functions to standard ones. Therefore, you've incorrectly assumed that the problem is in API differences, when in fact all of those promise based apis behave the same way in this respect and the actual problem is the syntactic context in which you use those apis

Comment: @ Aluan Haddad  Thanks, you were wright.